# Generator to change a C++ API into a C interface?

Tags: c++, c, interface, generator

Is there some kind of tool i can give a c++ header to and have it change the API/lib/interface into a C interface as well as generate the C functions to cast and call the C++ code?

Answer (score 4):

I think [SWiG](http://www.swig.org/) might do most of that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a tool that can do this automatically, it can get pretty tricky if you have classes as arguments to the public functions in your API.

But if your API is simple and mostly using native types, then you can do this by hand with not too much work. Here is a quick example of a C wrapper for a C++ class. Let's say this is the C++ class to wrap, let's call it `test.h`:

```
class Test {
public:
    Test();
    int do_something(char* arg);
    bool is_valid(); // optional, but recommended (see below)
};
```

This is your C header `test_c.h`:

```
typedef void* TestHandle;
TestHandle newTest();
int deleteTest(TestHandle h);
int Test_do_something(TestHandle h, char* arg);
```

And your C implementation will be a C++ file with C functions, let's say `test_c.cpp`:

```
extern "C" TestHandle newTest()
{
    return (void*)new Test();
}

extern "C" int deleteTest(TestHandle h)
{
    Test* this = static_cast<Test*>(h);
    if (!this->is_valid())
        return -1; // here we define -1 as "invalid handle" error
    delete this;
    return 0; // here we define 0 as the "ok" error code
}

extern "C" int Test_do_something(TestHandle h, char* arg)
{
    Test* this = static_cast<Test*>(h);
    if (!this->is_valid())
        return -1; // here we define -1 as "invalid handle" error
    return this->do_something(arg);
}
```

The `is_valid()` method is there to guarantee that you were not given a bad handle. For example, you can store a [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) in all your instances, then `is_valid()` just ensures the magic number is there.